# RTX 3080, Ubuntu 18.04, cuda 11.1, gcc 9.1.0, fail to install pytorch 1.7.1

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, nvidia

The NVIDIA driver is shown following:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYw5m.png)
I used anaconda and create a virtual environment to install pytroch 1.7.1, when I type the test code:

```
print(torch.rand(3,3).cuda())
```

There came the error:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQTUY.png)

This may caused by the error Geforce driver. But I have confirmed that the cuda, gcc and pytorch version are matched.
I installed pytorch 1.7.0，1.6.0 and I got the same results.

Next, I created another environment and installed pytorch 1.5.0. After I typed the same test code, 5 minutes later I could see the result:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLpzk.png)
If I run this code again, I can get the result right away. But if I exit the python and come into python again, when run this test code in the first time I have to wait again.
How to solve this problem or which pytorch and cuda version should I install? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the cuda toolkit isnt compatible with 3080 yet, I think I heard that you have to compile pytorch yourself to make it work with 3080 but Im not sure